# Magento2 Is Varnish cache helpful with https?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am planning to install Varnish Cache in my Magento2 Website, but I have a question will Varnish cache actually helpful for me as my is in https?

- Being in https won't it just not ignore the traffic?
- Can someone guide me on this?